# Without @Repository annotation the code works fine and with annotation also works fine. What is the difference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

we can declare repository classes in this way

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer>
```

and this way

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer>
```

What is the difference between this two approach mentioned. Because if we remove the `@Repository` annotation then the code will work fine then what is the difference, can anyone explain me on this.

Comment: There isn't the `@Repository` doesn't do anything on an interface and Spring Data has other means of detecting beans.

Answer (score 11):

While the other answers go into detail about the sterotype annotations they don't document why exactly its not needed, its a Spring Boot feature - not Spring Framework.

With Spring Boot, it will automatically scan child packages from the main SpringBootApplication class and detect repository interfaces and create beans for you with the use of Autoconfiguration that is part of the `SpringBootApplication`

> Spring Data repositories usually extend from the Repository or CrudRepository interfaces. If you use auto-configuration, repositories are searched from the package containing your main configuration class (the one annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication) down.

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories

If you were not using Spring Boot, or the repository was not in package, or child-package, of the Spring Boot Application it would need to be annotated and the package scanned, or a bean created.

> Spring Data can create implementations of @Repository interfaces of various flavors. Spring Boot handles all of that for you, as long as those @Repositories are included in the same package (or a sub-package) of your @EnableAutoConfiguration class.

> For many applications, all you need is to put the right Spring Data dependencies on your classpath. There is a spring-boot-starter-data-jpa for JPA, spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb for Mongodb, etc. To get started, create some repository interfaces to handle your @Entity objects.

> Spring Boot tries to guess the location of your @Repository definitions, based on the @EnableAutoConfiguration it finds. To get more control, use the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation (from Spring Data JPA).

See the documentation for more information on this behavior e.g. taking more control over the creation of repositories.

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-spring-data-repositories

Comment: did you happen to try this? cause you are wrong. I do not know how you understood those lines in spring-boot documentation, but `@Repository` on the interface means ZERO for spring-boot, It can pick it up be that in the same package (or child) or a completely un-related package (with `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`). Again : it does not matter if you put `@Repository` on an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, I believe that's what I stated.

Comment: _If you were not using Spring Boot, or the repository was in a child package **it would need to be annotated** and the package scanned_

Comment: I don't understand your edit now, since you left a weird _or the repository was not in package_, which sort of does not make sense. But anyway, this is still incorrect.

Comment: @Eugene please suggest an edit then rather than being passive aggressive

Comment: my bad, indeed a bit rough. my point was that you still suggest that there is some value in adding `@Repository` to an interface via "If you were not using Spring Boot, or the repository was not in package, or child-package, of the Spring Boot Application it would need to be annotated and the package scanned...". so if you can edit and make sure that you mention there is no value in that. do I make sense? I will remove the comments once you do that btw

Comment: ah I think I see what you're suggesting. I might write up a repo, but given this is a spring boot question you're right that there is no value in the `@Repository` and would just need to scan whatever package you're repository is in if it isn't a child package in a spring boot application - is that correct?

Comment: right! The `@Repository` on an interface is not needed, ever :)

Answer (score 4):

`@Repository` is a special type of `@Component` and we annotate the interface which acts as a repository with `@Repository` annotation. `@Repository` deals with catching exceptions that are related to data persistence.

We don't need to use `@Repository` annotation when we are extending `JpaRepository` because Spring detects that the predefined `JpaRepository` has been extended and recognises the interface that extends `JpaRepository` as a repository.

Answer (score 1):

`@Repository` annotation is used to indicate that the class provides the mechanism for **storage, retrieval, search, update and delete** operation on objects.

Spring ***Repositor***y annotation is a specialization of **@Component** annotation, so Spring Repository classes are autodetected by spring framework through classpath scanning.

**@Repository** is used to create Bean. If you are not using this annotation then there can be some other way you are creating the bean, therefore, it does not make any difference for you.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the spring documentation:

> The @Repository annotation is a marker for any class that fulfills the role or stereotype of a repository (also known as Data Access Object or DAO). Among the uses of this marker is the automatic translation of exceptions, as described in Exception Translation.

It serves mainly as a stereotype marker, but @Repository is a specialization of @Component, which spring uses for classpath scanning.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations

https://www.journaldev.com/21460/spring-repository-annotation

Comment: This doesn't explain why it isn't needed.

Comment: It depends on your setup, if you have Component or Service in comibination with Repository then you wouldn't need to define it, but you need to have one of the three annotations in order for springs autowiring to work, since these annotations create beans for you. If you have another mechanism in your application to create beans from JpaRepository implementing interfaces then, ofcourse, it would work without annotations, otherwise you should've been getting a "bean couldn't be found" error on build.

Comment: It's due to Spring boot picking up the interface.